# Moment.js string formatting deprecation error driving me nuts

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Lots of posts about a similar question, but I've followed their advice and haven't been able to fix anything. I'm recieving the following deprecation error when using moment.js

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions

Now, I understand that this error is given because moment.js wants me to specify the format for the date that I'm passing in, but I've done that and the deprecation error persists. I'm wondering if I'm misunderstood how I'm supposed to specify the string format? I'm including the sections of my code where I use moment.js below.

```
  const latestDate = moment(actualData[actualData.length - 1].date, 'MM/DD/YYYY');

  if (moment(actualData[0].date, 'MM/DD/YYYY').isBefore(fiveYearsBack)) {

  if (moment(dataPoint.date, 'MM/DD/YYYY').isAfter(fiveYearsBack)) {

  if (moment(dataPoint.date, 'MM/DD/YYYY').isAfter(fiveYearsBack)) {

  latestDate.subtract(5, 'years');
```

The '.date' properties that I'm accessing are strings, and look like 02/22/2022. My understanding is that this should fix the deprecation error, is there an additional step I need to take to clue moment.js in on the formatting of my strings?

EDIT: It's worth noting that everything WORKS the way it's supposed to, I just want to get rid of the console deprecation warning and feel like the code will stand up to any major releases in moment.js

EDIT 2: As per request, I'm including a sample of the actualData

```
actualData: [
  {date: "03/01/2014",
  target_id: 72
  value: "9.7900000000"}
]
```

EDIT 3: After removing all uses of moment from the offending page I'm still getting a deprecation error. This leads me to believe that the problem is buried somewhere in the application where I've used moment and forgot about it. I'll investigate further, thank you all for your help.

Comment: What version of moment are you using? Just so I can try to reproduce the error.

Comment: Version 2.20.1!

Comment: What is `fiveYearsBack`?

Comment: Testing in JSFiddle, I have not been able to reproduce the deprecation notice with strings like `'02/22/2022'`. So, additional information about `actualData` might be helpful to get a good answer.

Comment: actualData is an array that holds a number of datapoint objects. Each object has a date (a string in 'MM/DD/YYYY' format) as well as a value.

Comment: fiveYearsBack is a point of comparison I use from one the moment.js objects. I get it through the following section of code: latestDate.subtract(5, 'years');

Comment: What is `latestDate`? Just trying to find which is the source of Deprecation warning :) Are you able to provide a snippet/fiddle that prints that warning?